# Can I modify power-management settings on a laptop running Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, command-line, power-management

It's my first time running ubuntu server and I'm trying to figure out a way to prevent the machine from going into suspend mode (I'm guessing) when the Lid is closed on the Laptop.

Is it possible to stop the laptop from entering suspend mode when the lid is closed? Possibly without needing to install some GUI package.

Answer (score 1):

Power management is handled by `acpid`; `man 8 acpid` and poke around in `/etc/acpi/events`.

Comment: Then what you're seeing now is what the BIOS is configured to do in the absence of an ACPI handler in the OS.  You may or may not be able to tell the BIOS how to behave; if you can't, you'll need to install the `acpid` package.  You'll also want to `apt-get source --download-only acpi-support` and poke through it; actually installing the package requires X11 because many of the support scripts are for X11 multimedia foo.  (This is arguably a packaging bug.)

Answer (score 0):

change the /etc/systemd/logind.conf file so that the following 2 lines are uncommented:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
```

Comment: Can you describe what your solution is doing?